# Oracle DB expdp and impdp issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-dump

I have created many interlinked tables as user "SCOTT" in oracle DB.
I want to copy these tables plus their data to new user "PRODUCTION"

For exporting data from "SCOTT", i used :

./expdp  scott schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log  CONTENT=ALL

Now for importing it, when i am using command :

./impdp PRODUCTION directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=impdpSCOTT.log CONTENT=ALL

, notable is getting created in PRODUCTION.
The output of the above command (`IMDB`) is "Job "PRODUCTION"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed'.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add paraneter REMAP_SCHEMA=SCOTT:PRODUCTION. See the [impdb documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm). Without it, there is nothing in the export that is relevant to your production user.